# Mock class with missing dependencies

Tags: java, mocking

I have third party component which I want to mock but it returns class which have complex hierarchy and some of interfaces have static fields which initialized by some class which  not available in API. I don't need anything from hidden class.

Sample:
Assume we want to mock class MutableCombo which implements Combo. But interface Combo has fields initialized by Breaker. Breaker is part of implementation package and cannot be accessed by developer during compilation and tests.

```
public interface Combo{
    String FUU = Breaker.getFoo();
    String BAR = Breaker.getBar();
}
public class MutableCombo implements Combo;
```

I want to test my class which working with MutableCombo but cannot mock it because

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Breaker
    at Combo.<clinit>(Combo.java:36)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `part of implementation package`?

Comment: I use third party component. Component have 2 part - API and implementation package. As developer I can use only API part of component.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need an adapter here. You shouldn't be mocking types you don't own for starters. Treat `MutableCombo` as an implementation detail. For example:

```
public class ExampleMutableCombo implements IExampleMutableCombo
{
     public String DoFoo()
     {
         return Breaker.getFoo();
     }

     public String DoBar()
     {
         return Breaker.getBar();
     }
}
```

Make  your code use `IExampleMutableCombo`. This interface is now yours. Use this in your production code. As you own this interface you can mock this role -  you can introduce a fake combo for testing such as:

```
public class FakeExampleMutableCombo implements IExampleMutableCombo
{
     public String DoFoo()
     {
         return "Foo";
     }

     public String DoBar()
     {
         return "Bar";
     }
}
```

Now all your tests can work with the stubbed out class, while your production code can make use of the `ExampleMutableCombo`. The key is to "code to an interface", not a type.

Comment: basically we do this. but it's annoying. I hoped there is some brute force solution) but, as I see in answers, there is not.

Comment: @ainlolcat it might feel annoying, but this is a good practice. Push as much of the third party code to the edge of your system. Your domain should be the focus. The rest are just details that you should be free to swap at will providing they conform to the interface you expect. Take Breaker in your example, I could switch that out with MyBreaker. As long as it spits out Foo and Bar the rest of the app won't care. Now replace Breaker with Database or WebService and you have a powerful ability to change your programs with trivial effort.